# component Not show any data in nested list in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have created two components: the first component displays a list, and when an item is clicked, it should take the user to the second component which shows all details for that item. The first component works fine, but I am having trouble with the second one. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Services :

```
import { resturant } from "../../constant/resturant";

import Image from "next/image";
import Header from "./Header";
import Categories from "./Categories-List";

const Services = () => {
  const item = resturant;

  return (
    <section className="flex">
      <Image
        src={item.backgroundUrl}
        className="object-cover w-full  h-full"
        alt="Image alt text"
      />
      <div className="absolute flex flex-col w-full">
        <Header item={resturant} />
        <div className="mt-3 ">
          {item.categories.map((category,index) => (
            <Categories key={index} category={category} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Services;
```

**Categories**

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import CategorieItem from "./Categorie-Item";

const Categories = ({ category }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);
  const handleCategoryClick = (category_id) => {
    setSelectedCategory(category_id);
    console.log(category_id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      {router.pathname === "/services" ? (
        <Link href={`/services/${category.id}`} key={category.id}>
          <div
            className="flex mt-2 justify-center items-center cursor-pointer transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:scale-110"
            onClick={() => handleCategoryClick(category.id)}
          >
            <Image
              src={category.image}
              className="object-fill w-full h-[7.5rem]"
              alt={category.name}
            />
            <div className="absolute w-full h-[7.5rem] flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-[#00000054] ">
              <p className="font-Montserrat font-[700] text-[30px] leading-9 text-[#FEFEFE] capitalize ">
                {category.name}
              </p>
              <p className="font-Montserrat font-[400] text-[12px] text-[#FEFEFE] leading-3 capitalize mt-1">
                {category.description}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {selectedCategory && (
            <CategorieItem category={category} category_id={selectedCategory} />
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

**CategorieItem**

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";

const CategorieItem = ({ category, category_id }) => {
  console.log( category );
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      poihghjkl
      {category[category_id].products.map((product) => (
        <div key={product.name}>
          <h2>{product.name}</h2>
          <p>{product.description}</p>
          {/* <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} /> */}
          <p>Price: {product.price}</p>
          <p>Tax: {product.tax}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategorieItem;
```

and the data like this :

```
import background from "./background.png";
import logo from "./saraylogo.png";
import categorieImage from "./appetizer.png";
export const resturant = {
  name: "SARAY",
  businessType: "resturant",
  backgroundUrl: background,
  logourl: logo,
  location: "lattakia",
  phone: "099999999",
  categories: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "appetizer",
      description: "YOU GOT TO START WITH RIGHT APPETIZER",
      image: categorieImage,
      Services: [
        {
          
          name: "Fettoş",
          description:
            "Lorem , ipsum ,dolor ,sit amet, consectetuer , adipiscing  , elit, sed diam ",
          image: "./assest/Fettos.png",
          price: "6.000",
          Tax: "00.00",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Can you show your project file structure? Past an image of it for example?